# Add and execute xml tag into html file

Tags: html, xml, blockly

*I am using XML tag into my HTML file in order **to show some block. By block, I meant that I want to use blocky features.** But unfortunately, I am unable to show those block into my view. I am using the Django framework.
I have tried and wasted more than 2 days regarding this issue.*
It will be helpful if someone can suggest something to work with XML and blockly into HTML.

**I am adding my code in the following.**

```
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>

 </head>
 <body>

<p>
  <button onclick="showCode()">Show Python</button>
  <button onclick="runCode()" id="runcode">Run Python</button>
  <button onclick="save()" id="save">Save Combination</button>
  <button onclick="restore()" id="restore">Restore</button>
</p>
<div id="blocklyDiv"></div>
<xml id="toolbox">

  <category name="Logic" >
    <block type="controls_if"></block>
    <block type="logic_compare"></block>
    <block type="logic_operation"></block>
    <block type="logic_negate"></block>
    <block type="logic_boolean"></block>
    <block type="do_it"></block>
  </category>

  <category name="Loops" >
    <block type="controls_repeat_ext">
      <value name="TIMES">
        <block type="math_number">
          <field name="NUM">10</field>
        </block>
      </value>
    </block>
    <block type="controls_whileUntil"></block>
  </category>

  <category name="Math" >
    <block type="math_number">
      <field name="NUM">123</field>
    </block>
    <block type="math_arithmetic"></block>
    <block type="math_single"></block>
  </category>

  <category name="Text" >
    <block type="text"></block>
    <block type="text_length"></block>
    <block type="text_print"></block>
  </category>


</xml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a width and height to the `blocklyDiv` element and add script to inject blockly into the blocklyDiv element. Don't forget to include the blockly source files.

These are mentioned in the guide [here](https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/configure/web/fixed-size).

Working code -

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <script src="../google/blockly/blockly_compressed.js"></script>
    <script src="../google/blockly/blocks_compressed.js"></script>
    <script src="../google/blockly/msg/js/en.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <button onclick="showCode()">Show Python</button>
      <button onclick="runCode()" id="runcode">Run Python</button>
      <button onclick="save()" id="save">Save Combination</button>
      <button onclick="restore()" id="restore">Restore</button>
    </p>
    <div id="blocklyDiv" style="height: 480px; width: 600px;"></div>
    <xml id="toolbox" style="display: none">
      <category name="Logic">
        <block type="controls_if"></block>
        <block type="logic_compare"></block>
        <block type="logic_operation"></block>
        <block type="logic_negate"></block>
        <block type="logic_boolean"></block>
        <block type="do_it"></block>
      </category>

      <category name="Loops">
        <block type="controls_repeat_ext">
          <value name="TIMES">
            <block type="math_number">
              <field name="NUM">10</field>
            </block>
          </value>
        </block>
        <block type="controls_whileUntil"></block>
      </category>

      <category name="Math">
        <block type="math_number">
          <field name="NUM">123</field>
        </block>
        <block type="math_arithmetic"></block>
        <block type="math_single"></block>
      </category>

      <category name="Text">
        <block type="text"></block>
        <block type="text_length"></block>
        <block type="text_print"></block>
      </category>
    </xml>

    <script>
      var workspace = Blockly.inject('blocklyDiv', {
        toolbox: document.getElementById('toolbox')
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, I will definitely check this out. Can you provide any references like blogs or websites?

Comment: [blockly developer guide](https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/overview) is having most of the basic documentation needed. Apart from that you can also see the sample demos provided in the library. The code for these are in the demo folder of the library and it is hosted on the site [here](https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/demos/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, I have checked those demos and they were very helpful.